# Delete Processes (from Process Builder) before uninstalling the package

Tags: apex, process-builder

We've created few Processes (from Process Builder), which will be installed along with the Package installation. When we are trying to uninstall the package it gives an error saying that the Processes should be deleted from uninstalling. I'm trying to delete these Processes using APEX so that the uninstall will be successful.

Any suggestions are most welcome, thanks.

Comment: The processes will need to be deactivated before they can be deleted. Is this being done before you try the uninstall?.

Comment: No, we are not deactivating before uninstall. Is there a process to auto-delete them before/while uninstalling?

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head. Hopefully another community member will know for for sure. It may be that there needs to be a manual step to do it as documentation.